# Could not find the version that satisfies the requirement win32print

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I'm trying to install win32print on Windows 10 as follows:

```
pip3.exe install win32print
```

> ERROR: Could not find the version that satisfies the requirement win32print (from versions: none)
>   ERROR: No matching distribution found for win32print

How can I fix it and install win32print on Windows 10?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install **pywin32** instead:

```
pip install pywin32
```

and then use **win32print** like:

```
from win32 import win32print
```

Comment: On Python 3.11, I was able to access `win32print` by executing the last step as `import win32print` directly.

Answer (score 1):

`win32print` is [apparently](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2016-August/109477.html) contained within the [`pywin32` package](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/).

Try installing it; `pip3 install pywin32`.

Comment: Requirement allready satisfied and I still cannot import win32print

Comment: @xralf Please edit your original post to also include the import code and the exception you get.